# videojs Javascript api breaks with flash fallback

Tags: video.js

I'm using video JS to embed a video, and using a javascript to call a function when the video is done playing.

The problem is that in ie8 and lower, it uses a flash fall back. Is there anyway to get the flash fallback to trigger some sort of 'on video ended' event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using [video.js's API](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md) rather than that of an HTML5 video element which may or may not be present. This works:

```
<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg">
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<script>
  //Forcing flash tech
  videojs('MY_VIDEO_1',{"techOrder":["flash"]}).ready(function(){
    this.on('ended', function(e){
      alert('end');
    })
  });
</script>
```